# How to convert dBm to V/m, A/m², and W/m²

Tags: spectrum, decibel, units

Currently I am using a spectrum analyser (SA) Keysight N9020, with an antenna to get readings off the air.

The reading on the SA gives a reading of a unit, dBm.

However, I need to convert dBm to V/m, A/m<sup>2</sup>, and W/m<sup>2</sup>.

What are the formulae?

Comment: So this isn't possible because dBm is a unit of power. V/m and A/m^2, etc. are units of electromagnetic field intensities. There is a conversion for something like dBm/m^2

Comment: how do I make use of this dBm I read of the SA to calculate the V/m or A/m^2?

Comment: @arthuryeo read the information given to you by KingDuken.

Comment: I do understand that dBm represent Power, while V/m represent Electric Field Strength and A/m represent Magnetic Field Strength. However, I am doing a test to collect data from strategically planned position in a building. The only tools I have is a spectrum analyser which throw out dBm.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume all the power shown by the spectrum analyser is efficiently transferred from space to your antenna then that's a beginning. For this to be true, the antenna has to be matched to the 50 ohm input on the spectrum analyser and, that there are minimal losses. For minimal losses to occur, the antenna needs to be length-resonant at the frequency of interest i.e. a quarter wave monopole operated with the right frequency to make it quarter-wave resonant. If it isn't properly length-resonant then it's unlikely that you can assume that its losses are insignificant and that it can be effectively matched to 50 ohm.

So, once you have overcome this hurdle you need to estimate the effective aperture (\$A_e\$) for the antenna. Given that a monopole has a gain (\$G\$) of about 2 dB we can use this formula: -

$$A_e = G\cdot\dfrac{\lambda^2}{4\pi}$$

Or just use [this calculator](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/effective-antenna-aperture-calculator). The result is in square metres.

So, given that the power can be determined (within the constraints mentioned above) and we know the area, we can calculate how many watts per square metre are being received. The watts per metre can be broken into these: -

$$W/m^2 = V/m\cdot A/m$$

And, because we know that the impedance of free space is approximately 377 ohms we can say this: -

$$W/m^2 = \dfrac{V^2/m^2}{377}$$

That allows you to calculate the electric field.

Comment: Would you be able to advice if a spectrum analyser can be use to detect Electric Field Strength and Magnetic Field Strength?

Comment: @arthuryeo If you can measure electric field strength and the incident wave is a properly formed EM wave then the magnetic field strength will be 377 times smaller (as per the impedance of free space and ohms law).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a certain amount of RF power into an antenna, with some 3_D radiation pattern, 
then the input power (dBm) becomes "volts/meter" field strength of the E_field.

The energy spreads out, we presume on the surface of a sphere, and the energy density drops off as 1/Range^2. Thus 10X Range gives you 20dB lower energy density, which is what an antenna responds to and gathers up to feed into a coax cable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert these, they don't describe the same thing:

dBm (decibel of milliwatt) is a unit of power.

W/m² is a unit of power per area, so you need to relate the power you measure to some area. Maybe the effective antenna area you're using?

A/m² is a current area density, and now you're deep into electromagnetic field theory.

So, the fact that you're asking this points to you not really understanding what you're supposed to be measuring. Can't solve that for you – we don't know what the purpose of your measurement is, sorry.